# Excluding a category from frontpage but not from WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, functions, categories, homepage

I am successfully using this functions.php snippet to exclude category 3 from the WordPress homepage:

```
function exclude_category_home( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_front_page ) {
$query->set( 'cat', '-3' );
}
return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_home' );
```

Unfortunately it also excludes category 3 from this homemade WP-Query on a WPUM profile page tab:

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_ID = $current_user->ID;
    
// Query to show a specific Custom Field
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'fetcher', 'meta_value' => $user_ID ) );
  
// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
the_title();
endwhile;
 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

**Why is that..?**

PS. A premade query on another WPUM profile page tab works fine, starting like this:

```
$the_query = wpum_get_posts_for_profile( $data->user->ID );
```

Comment: Note that `pre_get_posts` is an action, not a filter, so `add_filter()` should be `add_action()`, and you don't need the `return` statement.

Comment: Adjusted and it works. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding [`$query->is_main_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_main_query/) to your `if` statement in `pre_get_posts` function. This will check if it's the main query for the page, and not a custom query.

Comment: Thank you Caleb! Perfect solution! ⭐
I’m surprised I couldn’t find that answer elsewhere.

Second line in my snippet now is:
`if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_front_page() ) {`